# Как комбинировать числа сумма которых равно

Tags: php, математика, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Есть 4 числа: Минимум, максимум, количество и сумма. Как найти все возможные варианты чисел от минимума до максимума сумма которых равно на заданной сумме и количество равно в заданной количестве. Пример : Минимум 4, максимум 6, сумма 30, количество 6. Возможные варианты должны бит:

5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 30

4 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 30

4 + 6 + 6 + 4 + 5 + 5 = 30
..........................

Есть ли какой нибудь алгоритм или математическая формула, для того чтобы вычислит эти варианты? Подскажите или покажите код пожалуйста.

Comment: Разложение числа N на K слагаемых в пределах от min до max (partition of n into k parts). Чтобы найти все варианты, формула не нужна, надо писать программу (проще всего рекурсивную)

Comment: brute force (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне кажется, что это решается с комощью "деревьев" - TreeNode;
Я точно не знаю, как это реализуется в PHP, но картинка тебе должна дать идею о том, как должно выглядеть.

За корень - root - ты берешь сумму(число). После прохождения по всем листьям ты проверяешь Path на то, что при последнем вычетании ты получаешь `0` и дальше ты выводишь на экран все числа, которые ты вычитал на протяжении этого "Path".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]